# How to read a custom header in Swashbuckle?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I used the following code to add a custom header to an operation:

```
public class RequestIdParameter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Swashbuckle.Swagger.Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation == null) return;

        if (operation.parameters == null)
        {
            operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
        }

        var requestParameter = new Parameter
        {
            description = "RequestId",
            @in = "header",
            name = "RequestId",
            required = true,
            type = "string"
        };

        operation.parameters.Add(requestParameter);
    }
}
```

But now I need to read that value. I tried this code, but the custom header does not exist:

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items.contains("requestId")
```

Comment: The name of the parameter is `RequestId`, but you are looking for the parameter `requestId`. Are you sure that it's not a case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: try HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["requestid"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Contains("RequestId")) 
{
    string value =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("RequestId").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

or

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestId", out headerValues))
{
    string value = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
}
```